# Vibration on widget click not working since API 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**EDIT** Thanks to [YP D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893054/vibration-on-widget-click-not-working-since-api-29/58414554#58414554), I have a solution. Added at the end

---

Ever since updating my Pixel 3 to android version 10 (API 29), my application's vibration is not working.

My app requests vibration permission, and has vibration working on earlier (< API 29) versions.
Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

When connecting my phone to Android Studio and looking at the logcat, I noticed these errors:

```
2019-09-11 18:46:28.622 1474-1546/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
2019-09-11 18:46:28.816 1474-3294/? E/VibratorService: Ignoring incoming vibration as process with uid = 10284 is background, usage = USAGE_UNKNOWN
```

My vibration code (durationMs is 50, but I tested with 500 too):

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(durationMs, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
} else {
    v.vibrate(durationMs);
}
```

I am running this code via an AppWidgetProvider class, that uses a Handler.postDelayed() thread to do some work.

I have not found anything related to this issue online.
What I assume is that since API 29, VibratorService has an issue with background apps.

If that is the case, I am not sure what approach should I take to bring the vibration to the foreground.

I have considered using a Service for the background work, but I found it easier to do work on Handler threads, so I could easily find my Widget view after I am done calculating, and wish to update the on-screen text.

---

Here is a **solution** based on YP D's answer:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
        .build();
VibrationEffect ve = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(durationMs,
        VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE);
v.vibrate(ve, audioAttributes);
```

The AudioAttributes seem to fix the vibration issue.

Comment: I'm also having this problem at the moment, can't seem to find any information about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem, You can use the following methods to solve

like this

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = {100, 1000, 100, 1000};
        if (mVibrator != null) {
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM) //key
                    .build();
            mVibrator.vibrate(pattern, 2, audioAttributes);
}
```

Comment: While actually working, your solution isn't perfect, as it causes a looping vibration that does not stop. I will post a modified solution based on this. Thanks!